# scrypt unable to install via authologic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I'm working with a Rails app that uses authlogic. The scrypt crypto algorithim is included (although not used). I'm gettting this error on my Mac. How do I resovle?

Why is i386 being thought as platform? I really don't care about scrypt - how can I get around this?

```
ld: in '/usr/local/lib/libunwind.dylib', file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/lib/libunwind.dylib for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [gcc -bundle -o x86_64-darwin/libscrypt_ext...]
/Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/ffi-compiler-1.0.1/lib/ffi-compiler/compile_task.rb:153:in `block in define_task!'
Tasks: TOP => default => x86_64-darwin/libscrypt_ext.bundle
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@ssui/gems/scrypt-3.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@ssui/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.1.0/scrypt-3.0.5/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing scrypt (3.0.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install scrypt -v '3.0.5'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  authlogic was resolved to 3.6.0, which depends on
    scrypt
```

Comment: I suppose you already looked at [this](https://github.com/pbhogan/scrypt/issues/64)?

Comment: I didn’t that’s a scary bug to read about.

Answer (score 4):

```
`bundle update scrypt`
```

The scrypt gem just released 3.0.6 that solves this issue.  It's not in the changelog but you can read the PR: https://github.com/pbhogan/scrypt/pull/72

Answer (score 2):

`scrypt` gem version `3.0.5` is causing the problem.

I was checking their [releases](https://github.com/pbhogan/scrypt/releases) and can not find `3.0.5`. 
The latest release is `3.0.3`

[`jvillian`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1359650/jvillian) may be right. The solution could be using `wtfiwtz` suggestion:

> Remove the references to `-arch i386` from `/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/scrypt-2.0.2/ext/scrypt/Rakefile` and `/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/scrypt-2.0.2/Rakefile` and then do this:

```
cp -R /Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/scrypt-2.0.2/ ~/Code/scrypt
cd ~/Code/scrypt
gem build scrypt.gemspec
gem install --local scrypt-2.0.2.gem
```

> I also had to comment out a line about the signing key in `scrypt.gemspec`

by checking [the `scrypt` `Rakefile` sourcecode](https://github.com/pbhogan/scrypt/blob/master/Rakefile#L31), I found the code that could be triggering the error. It is a mac specific issue (`if t.platform.mac?`).

```
desc "FFI compiler"
namespace "ffi-compiler" do
  FFI::Compiler::CompileTask.new('ext/scrypt/scrypt_ext') do |t|
    t.cflags << "-Wall -std=c99"
    t.cflags << "-msse -msse2" if t.platform.arch.include? "86"
    t.cflags << "-D_GNU_SOURCE=1" if RbConfig::CONFIG["host_os"].downcase =~ /mingw/
    t.cflags << "-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309L" if RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'].downcase =~ /linux/
    t.cflags << "-arch x86_64 -arch i386" if t.platform.mac?
    t.ldflags << "-arch x86_64 -arch i386" if t.platform.mac?

    t.add_define 'WINDOWS_OS' if FFI::Platform.windows?
  end
end
```